# Simple C++ unit test fails with access violation

Tags: unit-testing, visual-c++

I wrote a simple unit test that calls an exported function within an EXE that searches for the first space in a string.  When I attempt to call it, the internal call to memchr gets an access violation.  Calling _CrtCheckMemory() fails with an access violation as well.

My guess is that the CRT (C Run-Time) is not initialized in the EXE which is loaded by the unit test.  I moved the function to a DLL and it works perfectly.

While I have a workaround, I'd like to understand how to get the original unit test working while testing a function from an EXE.

To repro:

1. Create a new C++ console app from VisualStudio 2022 called AccessViolation
2. Add a native unit test called AccessViolationTest
3. Replace main() with

```
// AccessViolation.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>

__declspec(dllexport) size_t TestFromExe(const std::string& test)
{
    assert(_CrtCheckMemory()); // this fails
    size_t index = test.find(' '); // comment previous line and this fails
    return index;
}

int main()
{
    std::string test = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back";
    std::cout << "found at index " << TestFromExe(test);
}
```

4. Replace unit test with

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
__declspec(dllimport) size_t TestFromExe(const std::string& test);

namespace AccessViolationTest
{
    TEST_CLASS(AccessViolationTest)
    {
    public:
        
        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG) | _CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF);
            assert(_CrtCheckMemory());
            std::stringstream str;
            std::string test = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back";
            size_t index1 = test.find(' ');
            size_t index2 = TestFromExe(test);
            str << "index found at " << index1 << " and " << index2;
            Logger::WriteMessage(str.str().c_str());
        }
    };
}
```

5. Modify the properties of the unit test project to add the EXE .lib:  Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies: $(OutDir)AccessViolation.lib

Comment: I forgot to add that it only fails when running the unit test.  Running the console app works.  From "Test Explorer" I right-clicked the unit test and clicked "Debug"

Comment: Wait, you are trying to import from an EXE, not from a DLL, so the context is probably not what you think. Try creating a DLL project.

Comment: In the case of large legacy software, you don't always get the option of moving your code to DLLs.  The MS docs say you can unit test an EXE this way.  I'm trying to figure out how.  I've already stated that moving it to a DLL fixes the issue.  I was hoping for some magical CRT initialization function that I've been unable to find in the docs...

Comment: Are both projects built with ``/MDd``?

Comment: The projects are using /MDd.  I would think it would work with any of the threading options.